# How can I change the degree of bevel

Tags: bevel

[image]
As the image following showed, I always get a flat degree bevel while sometimes I need like 45 degrees bevel, what can I do for it, thanks!

Comment: Looks to me as though you've scaled your mesh in _Object Mode_ without applying. If that's the case, undo the bevel, go back to _Object Mode_, and apply the scale by hitting `Ctrl+A` followed by `S`.

Comment: ... Object-level transforms take place _after_ mesh modifications. While modelling,  _always_ transform in Edit Mode. I do wish modelling tutors would not. ever. scale in Object Mode :) .. we could  avoid a lot of the puzzled customers here on BSE ..

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has been solved

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm with you on this one. I always roll my eyes when tutors scale in _Object Mode_ and even worse, either not stress that if you do it that way it is important to apply the scale afterwards or just do it casually without mentioning applying it at all.